# Is there a way to add the scale value for transform in css using JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-transforms

I am trying to zoom in some images to fit into the window if the height of images are less using `Transform` in CSS.

But as my images are of different height uploaded by the users of my website so just by giving following css code its not zooming enough for different Images.

**CSS**

```
.small{
transform:scale(1.42,1.42);
-webkit-transform:scale(1.42,1.42);
-moz-transform: scale(1.42,1.42);
-o-transform:  scale(1.42,1.42);
-ms-transform:  scale(1.42,1.42);

/*transition: all 0.65s;
-webkit-transition: all 0.65s;
-moz-transition: all 0.65s;
-o-transition:  all 0.65s;
-ms-transition:  all 0.65s;*/
}
```

So now I wanted to add the `scale` value of `transform` dynamically using JS . What I have done till now is the following script

**SCRIPT**

```
function imageHandler() {
  var images = $('.rslides ').find('img');
   $('.rslides ').find('#bg').addClass('thumbnail');
    setTimeout(function () {
        images.each(function () { // jQuery each loops over a jQuery obj
            var mh=290;
            var h = $(this).innerHeight(); // $(this) is the current image

                if( h < mh)
                    {  
                       $(this).addClass('small');
                        var m = mh-h;
                        m = m/2;
                          // m = m + pginationH;
                        $(this).css('margin-top', +m + "px");
                        console.log("padding for small:",m);
                    }
                if(h > mh)
                    {
                        $(this).addClass('big');
                        var m = h-mh;
                        m = m/2;
                        //console.log(m); 
                        $('.big').css('margin-top',-m  +"px" ); 
                        console.log("padding for big:",m);

                     }    
 });
    }, 1000);
    }
```

The above script maps the image and add class `.small` if the height is less than 290 . So what I want to do is add `Transform` scale value according to the height of the image

Can any one help me out with this

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just pass in the `transform` property in the same way you passed in `margin-top` to your `.big` element. jQuery already handles the prefixing for you on the `transform` property, so you can simply pass in your new scale value like this:

```
$('.small').css({
    transform: 'scale(' + scale + ')'
});
```

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/u9k5B/1/).

For example, the `.small` element on Chrome will be given the `-webkit-transform` property whereas on Firefox it will be given the `-moz-transform` property.

As for how to generate the scale values, you can simply base these upon the maximum of `width` or `height` according to some base value:

```js
var height = $('.small').height(),
    width = $('.small').width(),
    largest = height > width ? height : width,
    base = 150,
    scale;

scale = base / largest;
```

Here the `base` value is 150. If the largest of the `height` or `width` is 300, for example, the scale will become `0.5` (as 150 / 300 = 0.5).

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/u9k5B/2/).

Comment: I wanted to know how to calculate the value to put inside the scale variable. I mean how much should I put when image is less than 290 in height ?. bcoz there could be image of height 230  or 250 so both should be zoomed differently right ?

Comment: @VikramAnandBhushan I've added a new JSFiddle demo as well. Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks yes it works bro   Though I have one more question and that is . I also have media query written in my page what it does is remove the extra zoom amount when then phone changes from portrait to landscape . I tried adding transition scale(1) !important but it doesnot help

Comment: @VikramAnandBhushan did you meant to put `transition` there instead of `transform` or is that a typo? Are you remembering to add the vendor prefixes (`-webkit`, `-moz`, etc.)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54914/discussion-between-vikram-anand-bhushan-and-james-donnelly).

Answer (score 1):

You can set up a variable with the value you want to scale by and use jQuery's css function on the element you want to scale, adding your variable as below:

```
var scaleValue = 2;

$('.element-to-scale').css({
    transform: 'scale(' + scaleValue + ')'
});
```

*As James mentioned, jQuery handles prefixing so I've removed them from my example*

Comment: okay. But how can I find the equivalent scaleValue for the images . How I should measure it

Comment: Is it relative to the height/width of the image, so for example, if the images is 300x300 scale by 2, 350x350 scale by 1.5 etc... or is it just dependent on whether the image is above/below a specified size?